# is there an alternative for Environment Injector plugin for passing information from one jenkins task to another

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have one Jenkins tasks that trigger another one and I want to pass some key-value pairs to the downstream one. Right now I'm using [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) and setting those key-values pairs inside a properties file.

For example, if a downstream Jenkins task has a *build parameter* named *param1* then if you put *param1=value1* inside the upstream task properties file, then the task will be triggered with *param1* set to *value1*. The problem of passing information like that means I need to expose build params that should not actually be exposed.

How can I hide these param? or what are easy alternative to pass key values pairs to next task..?